# Select as or select

Tags: sentence-construction

> She was **selected as/selected** the most beautiful girl in her school.

Which one is correct? 
My book says selected as is correct.But i don't think so.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence, with the word **select**, the preposition **as** meaning **in the role of** is required.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20selected%20as%20the%2Cwas%20selected%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20selected%20as%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20selected%20the%3B%2Cc0) shows that "was selected as the" is common and "was selected the" does occur very occasionally, but if you look at actual instances, they are all examples of sentence spanning "was selected. The".

This sentence is therefore the only correct version:

> She was selected as the most beautiful girl in her school.

Interestingly, if you use the word **vote**, no preposition is required: "was voted the" is common but "was voted as the" does occur occasionally.

> She was voted the most beautiful girl in her school.